# adding new pages visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

My friend sent me today a new .xaml pages for windows phone app. I put .xaml and .xaml.vb files inside my app folder but visual doesn't see them. What files do I need to replace so that visual could see them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to press the "Show all files" button at the top of your Solution Explorer. Then you should see a "ghost" icon of the files you've added. Right click and "include in project".

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on the project in solution explorer - and then choose "add existing items".

Alternatively, it might be better if your friend sends you her project file - or if you use a source control system to share files - this might help you avoid future problems.